# ASP.NET Core Identity returns 404 instead of 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

I am trying to use ASP Identity with a .NET 8 Web API. I have the following in my `Program.cs`.

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme)
    .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme, options =>
    {
        options.ClaimIssuer = "test";
    });
services.AddAuthorization();
services
    .AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then later on, I call the middleware:

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapIdentityApi<MyUser>();
// etc.
```

So now I can register an account just fine and I can access the `/login` endpoint without trouble. However, when I try to call a controller action, I get a 404. Why?

```cs
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() => Ok();
```

Another thing I wonder is: I also get a 404 if I don't pass a Bearer token in the headers, why? Why 404 and not 401 or 403?

If I remove the `Authorize` attribute, it works fine. Why would it return 404 if I send a token, though?

EDIT: When I explicitly set which scheme to use in the `[Authorize]` attribute, it works. Why does it not use the default scheme which I specified in `Program.cs`?

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Bearer")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is done by design as described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-with-identity-in-dotnet-8/)

Somewhere down the line it says:

> To test the app, run it and navigate to the Swagger UI. Expand the secured endpoint, select try it out, and select execute. The endpoint is reported as `404 - not found`, which is arguably more secure than reporting a `401 - not authorized` because it doesn’t reveal that the endpoint exists.

### Edit

When adding Identity to your project using `services.AddIdentity()` authentication is added as well and it uses cookie as default authentication and challenge scheme. If you want to use only bearer token for authentication you can do this by modifying your registration like so:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.BearerScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.BearerScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
})
   .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme, options =>
   {
       options.ClaimsIssuer = "test";
   });
```

It will set the Bearer scheme as default challenge scheme because currently Identity sets this to cookie. Hope this helps

Comment: Fair, but why would it return 404 if I send a token as well, though?

Comment: @JrDeveloper Maybe the token is invalid, might not contain the issuer you have set in your code. Try debugging and checking the logs. Set the log levels to debug and investigate in the logs maybe it will help.

Comment: Can't debug basically anything because it's all hidden under a Microsoft NuGet package.
If I set `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Bearer")]`, it works.

Comment: This is probably because when calling `AddIdentity` it sets some default authentication schemes, if you want only Bearer try setting it explicitly as a default challenge scheme too.

Comment: That has actually worked. Can you please edit your answer above so I can mark it as correct?